# map and shared_ptr error: ‘__d’ cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++11, dictionary, copy, shared-ptr

I'm trying to map domain names to OpenSSL context objects

```
using SSL_CTX_ptr = std::shared_ptr<SSL_CTX>;
typedef map<string, SSL_CTX_ptr> DomainContexts;
...

static DomainContexts contexts;
...

string domain = "example.com"
SSL_CTX_ptr ctx(CreateServerContext(domain), ::SSL_CTX_free);
contexts.insert(std::pair<string, SSL_CTX_ptr>(domain, ctx));
```

`CreateServerContext` returns a `SSL_CTX*`:

```
SSL_CTX* CreateServerContext(const string& domain)
{
    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(...);
    ...

    return ctx;
}
```

The code is producing the following compiler error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/memory:87,
                 from /home/ac-project/include/ac-common.h:42,
                 from ../source/ac-openssl-2.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of ‘std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(_Ptr, _Deleter) [with _Ptr = std::nullptr_t; _Deleter = long int; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:798:35:   required from ‘std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t, _Deleter) [with _Deleter = long int; _Tp = ssl_ctx_st; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr.h:147:37:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t, _Deleter) [with _Deleter = long int; _Tp = ssl_ctx_st; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]’
../source/ac-openssl-2.cpp:82:38:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:482:8: error: ‘__d’ cannot be used as a function
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Sp_counted_deleter<_Ptr, _Deleter, _Alloc, _Lp>::_M_dispose() [with _Ptr = std::nullptr_t; _Deleter = long int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]’:
../source/ac-openssl-2.cpp:549:1:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:350:9: error: ‘((std::_Sp_counted_deleter<std::nullptr_t, long int, std::allocator<int>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>*)this)->std::_Sp_counted_deleter<std::nullptr_t, long int, std::allocator<int>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>::_M_del.std::_Sp_counted_deleter<std::nullptr_t, long int, std::allocator<int>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>::_My_Deleter::_M_del’ cannot be used as a function
```

I think the error has to do with copying the `shared_ptr`, but I also thought `shared_ptr` was copyable.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which line is `ac-tls-server.cpp:84`, and which is `ac-tls-server.cpp:551`?

Comment: Ah, OK. I see what I did wrong. I assumed it was the code I was working on (shown above). I knocked things loose in another file (lines 84 and 551) when I reworked `CreateServerContext`. Let me go ahead and cast the close vote.

Comment: My bad Igor... Here was line 82: `SSL_CTX_ptr ctx(NULL, NULL);` It was valid when `SSL_CTX_ptr` was a `unique_ptr`. When I moved to a `map` to cache the context, I changed the type to a `shared_ptr` so it could be copied.